# How can I return a string value from a component that is a React Context Consumer

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-context

I have a React component that is a consumer of a Context Provider. I am using this for a translation component for internationalization.  My consumer is basically a wrapper around the React Context Consumer element and calls an underlying translate function.  My problem is, I want to just return the STRING value from this component, but it actually returns a React element which breaks my interfaces. Is it possible to "unwrap" this and just give me the string?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {IIntlContext, IntlContext} from 'Common/Intl/IntlProvider';

export default (key: string) => {

    // I JUST WANT THE STRING!

    return (
        <IntlContext.Consumer>
            {
                (context: IIntlContext) => {
                    return context.translate(key);
                }
            }
        </IntlContext.Consumer>
    );
};
```

The provider wraps my whole React app and looks like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface IIntlProviderProps {
    locale: string;
    i18n: any;
    children: React.ReactNode;
}

interface IIntlProviderState {
     locale: string;
     i18n: any;
}

export interface IIntlContext extends IIntlProviderState {
    translate: (key: string) => any;
}

export const IntlContext = React.createContext<IIntlContext | undefined>(
    undefined
);

export class IntlProvider extends React.Component<IIntlProviderProps, IIntlProviderState> {
    constructor(props: IIntlProviderProps) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            locale: props.locale,
            i18n: props.i18n
        };
    }

    public translate = (key: string) => {
        return this.state.i18n.t(key);
    };

    public render() {
        const context: IIntlContext = {
            ...this.state,
            translate: this.translate
        };

        return (
            <IntlContext.Provider value={context}>
                {this.props.children}
            </IntlContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}


export default IntlProvider;
```

My goal is to just be able to import the consumer and pass it a string to translate like this:

```
import translate from 'Common/Intl/Translator';

translate('some text');
```

Comment: Hi, @Donuts. Have you found a proper solution?